# Can one mount a FileVault 2 encrypted drive from Windows?

Tags: hard-drive, windows, external-disk, filevault, encryption

I encrypted an external drive with FileVault 2. Now it would be great if I could access it from a Windows PC. Is this outright impossible? I found no definitive answer either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of writing there is no software that natively supports working with FileVault 2 encrypted drives within Windows.

There are ways to access the content of a FileVault 2 encrypted volume on other platforms including Windows (for example [libfvde](https://github.com/libyal/libfvde)), assuming you have the passkey and sufficient patience, but none that allow an encrypted volume to be used as a regular drive on Windows.

At the moment, to the best of my knowledge, there isn't even any software that allows Windows to natively understand drives that use unencrypted CoreStorage volumes.